# test if a folder exist or not in google drive

Tags: vb.net, google-drive-api, directory, exists

I want to know if folder (subfolder) exist in google drive or not , after searching in this [page](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/search-parameters) , i try to do it , i create a boolean function which return true if folder exist .

here is a code of boolean function

```
 Public Function exist(v As String) As Boolean
    Dim pag As String
    Dim req = Service.Files.List()
    req.Q = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
    req.PageToken = pag
    Dim result = req.Execute()
    If (result.NextPageToken IsNot Nothing) Then
        Return False
    Else
        Return True
    End If

End Function
```

and here  how i call it

```
 If (exist(dat_sauv.SelectedItem) = False) Then
        MessageBox.Show("folder exist")

    End If
```

the exception is

[image]

exception has declenched in exist method in this insctruction

Dim result = req.Execute()

is my method correct or not ? can you help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.

1. Improper query

Your line `req.Q = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"` 
should be

`req.Q = "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and name = '"+v+"' and trashed=false"`
You'll probably need to tidy up the quoting and escaping (ie Don't copy/paste and expect it to work first time)

2. use of nextPageToken

The presence of the folder will not be indicated by the presence of nextpageToken. Instead, you need to check the files array within the response for >0 elements.

Comment: thank you , for the first , i add trashed=false
but the next , i don't understand

Comment: 1. why did you add trashed=false. You should use the full query i gave you. 2. read the documentation to understand what nextPageToken does. Also use the "try now" feature at https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list#try-it to help you understand how it works

Comment: Ok , i will try this api 
in my code , i add req.Q = "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' AND '" + v + "' and trashed=false" and i use for each boucle but the same exeception in same place

v is folder name

Comment: please read my answer carefully. you have still got the Q wrong